# Mac OS Big Sur with iOS Simulator iPhone X(12.0) Not working with error _ReportRPCTimeout

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, simulator, macos-big-sur

I hope everyone is doing great!

I am developing a game using unity version 2020.1.17f1 which is for the android and ios platforms. And it has social login SDK's from Facebook, Google, Twitter, and iOS.

The build was running fine for both of the platforms until I updated my Mac OS to the latest one 11.1 (Mac OS Big Sur). I did not update XCode yet because my colleague using XCode 11.7 to make and build for iOS. Meaning I have to use XCode 11.7 to make and build!

Now, my problem is:
I am creating an iOS build from unity using Simulator SDK and with:

- Metal helper enabled
- .Net framework version 4.x

Project build running fine!

Now importing this project to XCode and making build was fine, as soon as I try to run this application no Simulator it stuck at a black screen, and throwing error with following details:

```
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Renderer: Apple Software Renderer
Vendor:   Apple Inc.
Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-17.0.34
GLES:     2
GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_sync GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_APPLE_texture_packed_float GL_IMG_
read_format GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 2.0> ; Context handle 34021152
OPENGL LOG: OpenGLES2 is deprecated on this platform
Initialize engine version: 2020.1.17f1 (9957aee8edc2)
2021-01-02 10:26:32.740379+0530 NewUnityProject1[6860:93127] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOBufferManager.cpp:226:GetIOBuffer:  HALB_IOBufferManager::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
2021-01-02 10:26:32.740975+0530 NewUnityProject1[6860:93127] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOBufferManager.cpp:226:GetIOBuffer:  HALB_IOBufferManager::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
2021-01-02 10:26:32.753355+0530 NewUnityProject1[6860:93127] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (1): output stream 0: null buffer
2021-01-02 10:26:32.753616+0530 NewUnityProject1[6860:93127] [aqme] 1640: EXCEPTION thrown (-50): -
2021-01-02 10:26:41.097627+0530 NewUnityProject1[6860:92923] RPCTimeout.mm:55:_ReportRPCTimeout: Start: Mach message timeout. Apparently deadlocked. Aborting now.
```

At UnityAppController file on line 130 with function name UnityInitApplicationGraphics().

Until now I thought my programming was bad! but to make sure I try to create a plain project in unity and follow the same steps, and I am shocked when I see the same result on a very blank project with one text view on it!

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? How can I test this application on the simulator?

[image: Unity Project Configuration]

[image: XCode and Simulator]

Thanks in advance

Comment: try running simulator with ios 14.0+